# Jobs in azure depending on jobs from other stages (inside templates)

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines, gitlab-ci, azure-pipelines-yaml

Migrating from `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `azure-pipelines.yml`. In the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I havee a scenario where one job(in the deploy stage) needs two other jobs(from test stages) for its execution

```
.deploy
 stage: deploy
 needs:
    - testmethod1
    - testmethod2

deployPROD:
 extends: .deploy
```

### Now here, does the deployProd job executes the testmethods again or just checks if they have been executed?

Moving to azure context, I created a templatefolder in my repository, with test file just to replicate this scenario.

My `azure-pipelines.yml` file is as shown below:

```
trigger:
- azure-pipelines

pool:
   vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: InitialA
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from initial A
- job: InitialB
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from initial B
- job: Subsequent
  dependsOn:
  - templates/test1.yml/testme
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from subsequent
```

I used the `dependsOn` key to show the depending jobs. Now the structure of the repo, along with the template file, looks like this:

[image: Show structure]

But I end up getting the following error :

[image: Error]

**So is my approach correct? Am I using the correct keywords in azure? if yes, what is the path that I need to consider in the `dependsOn`key?**

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template job and the Subsequent job can `dependsOn` the template job.
Please refer [Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for more template usages in Azure Pipeline.
Code sample:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: InitialA
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from initial A
- job: InitialB
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from initial B
- job: templates
  steps:
  - template: test.yml  # Template reference
- job: Subsequent
  dependsOn:  templates
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from subsequent
```